# Leaflet How to set center map when click marker

Tags: leaflet

I follow this example http://jsfiddle.net/abenrob/ZkC5M/ , When i click marker I want map pan to marker and set position center screen my code is below but when i click map.setView(new L.LatLng(position), 5);
is not working.

```
 function markerFunction(id){
        for (var i in markers){
            var markerID = markers[i].options.title;
            var position = markers[i].getLatLng();

            if (markerID == id){              
                map.setView(new L.LatLng(position), 5);
                markers[i].openPopup();
            };
        }
    }
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The example that you're following illustrates how to interact with markers by clicking on links *outside of the map*, and the function that you're editing is only called when you click on one of those links. It will not affect the behavior of clicking on the markers themselves.

If you replace `new L.LatLng(position)` with `position` in your edited function, clicking on the *links* will cause the map to center on the associated marker, but your question is about how to get the same behavior from clicking on the markers themselves.

To do that, you can create a function to be called when a marker is clicked:

```
function clickZoom(e) {
    map.setView(e.target.getLatLng(),5);
}
```

and then attach a click event listener to each marker by appending `.on('click', clickZoom)` when you create the layer, for example:

```
var marker1 = L.marker([51.497, -0.09], {
  title: "marker_1"
}).addTo(map).bindPopup("Marker 1").on('click', clickZoom);
```

Here is an updated fiddle showing all this at work:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZkC5M/221/

Answer (score 10):

[panTo()](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-panto) should work too:

```
marker.addEventListener("click", function (e){
  map.panTo(this.getLatLng());
});
```

for your example, it looks like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < markers.length; i++){
    markers[i].addEventListener("click", function(e){
        map.panTo(this.getLatLng());
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In practice, the `panTo()` and `setView()` behave differently.

To load the map with the view, use `setView()` when creating the map object:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([lat, long], 5);
```

To watch the map move / pan, use with one of these after creating the map object:

```
map.setView([lat, long], 5);
```

or:

```
map.panTo([lat, long]);
```

Note: `setView()` allows you to set the Zoom, while `panTo()` only supports position.